# JavaEE - TomEE (Tomcat v9.0) - An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy])

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I'm kind of new to JavaEE and I'm just totally lost on this issue. I tried running my project on the TomEE Plume 8.0.0 server, but I simply cannot get it to work. I tried a lot of various stuff, mostly searched around everywhere, but I'm still confused as to what is causing this issue. This is the severe error I keep getting:

```
Dec 07, 2018 5:23:53 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MusicRecordingStudio]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:845)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1654)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1634)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:769)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2414)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1096)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:761)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1308)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1130)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

It's followed by a bunch of errors about not being able to deploy my sessionBeans, and then just tells me that it cannot run.

What's the best way to figure out where the problem is, please?

I'm using the newest Eclipse EE (20180917-1800), running Linux Mint 19 Tara, with java-11-openjdk-amd64 linked to the project.

Edit: Alright, I tried out various version of OpenJDK, even the newest JRE, but I'm still coming up empty on this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found it by searching Google regarding the same problem.

I fixed the problem simply by making sure my database was running before I started TomEE. Without a running database, JPA can't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble. Fix by adding JPA facet to my project.